# Simplest way to retain values between angular pages?

Tags: angularjs

I'm on page **x**. I click an action on page **x** which updates (with ajax) 3 div elements with new text.

Then I navigate to page **y** (with an angular request), and then back to page **x** - the values I changed with ajax are now gone (they are default).

My values are not inside a form, but rather inside a div element.

What is the simplest way to retain values between switching pages in angular in case some of them are changed (for example with ajax)?

Comment: Assuming you have a SPA when you're switching pages - then you can persist the data in a service or factory which will be cached as a singleton.

Comment: Use an Angular service. Bind your DIV values to members exposed on your service. The service values will persist between pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest? Set values on $rootScope.

```
$rootScope.name = name;
```

Now just inject $rootScope in any controller that needs name.

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('CtrlA', function($rootScope) { 
  $rootScope.name = "something";
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('CtrlB', function($rootScope) { 
  console.log($rootScope.name);
});
```

If you start to add a lot of values to rootScope you're probably better off using a [service](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-services.html).

The service equivalent for something simple like a name is this:

```
angular.module('myModule').service('Name', function Name() {
  var name;

  var service = {       
   getName: function() { return name; },
   setName: function(n) { name = n; }
  };
  return service;
});
```

Then you can inject this service in different controllers.

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('CtrlC', function(Name) { 
  Name.setName('hello world!');
});

angular.module('myModule').controller('CtrlD', function(Name) { 
  $scope.name = Name.getName();
  console.log($scope.name);
});
```

Comment: How would I output the root variable in my view?

Comment: Just like any other scope variable - `{{name}}`

Comment: is this applicable for Angular 1.5 component routing as well? I hv posted a que on stackoverflw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657136/how-to-retain-values-while-navigating-across-pages-using-component-routing-angul/  I apprecaite if u can u hav a look

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options

1. Save your data to [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)
2. Create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to store your data.
3. Save your data to [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)

Comment: 4. pass id in url and fetch the object. 5. localStorage

Comment: @Sobieck00 I agree that services are usually the better option.